# Axis tick alignment issue with ggplot2 theme_article and expand = expansion(0)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm encountering an alignment problem with my ggplot2 graph when using the `theme_article` from the "egg" library along with `expand = expansion(0)` for the y axis. Specifically, the y=0 axis tick mark is not properly aligned with the panel border. See the figure below for a comparison between `theme_classic` (where the problem does not occur) and `theme_article`.

[image]

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 0:9,
  y = 0:9
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_article() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(0))

ggsave(~/figure.pdf, height = 8.33, width = 12.5, unit = "cm")
```

In RStudio, the figure is rendered like I want, but it is the exported pdf figure in which the problem occurs.

I tried changing the linewidth of the panel border and the tick marks, but this does not seem to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the artifact is caused by clipping. Setting "clip" parameter to "off" removes the misalignment:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_article() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(0))+
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]